# Data ID keeps coming back undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some stupid reason the data-id keeps coming back undefined.

```
            <div class="slideshow-nav">
                <div class="slideshow-nav-button" data-id"slideShow1">1</div>
                <div class="slideshow-nav-button" data-id"slideShow2">2</div>
                <div class="slideshow-nav-button" data-id"slideShow3">3</div>
                <div class="slideshow-nav-button" data-id"slideShow4">4</div>
                <div class="slideshow-nav-button" data-id"slideShow5">5</div>
            </div>
```

I've also replaced the data-id with a regular id with no effect.

JS

```
$('.slideshow-nav-button').click(function(){
    var slideShowNextSlide = $(this).data('id');
});
```

This isn't working either

```
$('.slideshow-nav-button').click(function() {
    var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(currentId);
    alert(currentId);
});
```

Comment: `data-id"slideShow1"` -> `data-id="slideShow1"`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo (missing `=`)

Answer (score 3):

```
data-id"slideShow1"
```

should be:

```
data-id="slideShow1"
```

And same with the rest, of course.

Comment: haha! I have definitely been up too long, it's always something dumb... Thanks Jason